# xPage as Welcome Page

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I am trying to setup xPage as Welcome page for notes client and to be deployed via policies. Only issue it opens up 2 window, one which is Bookmarks.nsf frameset and second one is the xPage. Tried many different ways to close frameset, but some internal setting doesn't like this since its a welcome page frame... any ideas or if somebody has done similar project.

I tried opening a view thru welcome page which opens up the xPage and then to close the view in Postopen event, but no luck. also tried same with Form.

Appreciate help .. badly stuck in it.

Comment: did you try to open xpage by notes:// link?

Comment: Yes, and it opens up 2 windows, one frameset and second is the xPage

Comment: I tried this before and blogged:

http://lotusnotus.com/lotusnotus_en.nsf/dx/an-experiment-with-xpages-homepage-for-notes-client.htm

I didn't test under load, but you might design a composite application and put any XPage as a component.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is:

1. open your xpage in the client
2. right click on the tab and create a new bookmark for it
3. right click on the newly created bookmark and click "set bookmark as home page"

I don't know if you can do that via policies, but at least it works if I do it interactively

Comment: thanks, but this needs to be done for about 1000 users .. that's why need thru policy document

Comment: Any idea where this 'Set Bookmark as home page" property is stored

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't really think this is in the local bookmark.nsf itself. Probably somewhere in the workspace?. Sorry, but there's not much more I can say about that...

Answer (score 1):

You can set this by policy by adding to the ini
StartupDB = 
That will load the NSF every time the client opens. This command does not respect the enforce flag as its enforced by default, do not set the enforce flag...

You can also set the nsf to replicate by policy so remote users will be able to open it as well.

Comment: But then Client will open up your default home page plus this startdb .. I want one window